# onClickListener doesn't work with RecyclerView items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

My main activity (the one containing the RecyclerView) looks like this:

```
myList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_list);
myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, getData());
myList.setAdapter(myAdapter);
myList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

Then I have a MyViewHolder,

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ...
    public Button addButton;
    public View root;
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ...
        addButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.add_button);
        root = itemView;
    }
    ...
}
```

and then, an adapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <MyViewHolder>{
    private LayoutInflater myInflater;

    List<MyModel> data = Collections.emptyList();

    Context context;

    public MyAdapter (Context context, List<MyModel> data) {
        myInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data = data;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_item, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return myViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ...
        holder.addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d("Hello", "Added");
            }
        });
        holder.root.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d("Hello", "Rooted");
            }
        });
    }
...
}
```

As can be seen from above, I have a RecyclerView item that has a button as a child. While clicking on the childButton, the onClickListener works and I get `Added` printed. But when I click on the item as a whole (the root), nothing happens. Why doesn't the root onClickListener work?

I am a real beginner with Android, so I am not sure where I am going wrong.

### Edit

`my_item.xml` looks something like:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
         android:clickable="true"> <-- this is the problem as correctly pointed out by user13
        <RelativeLayout>
            <TextView>
            <LinearLayout>
                <TextView>
                <TextView>
                <TextView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout>
            <Button>
            <Button>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to add the following attribute to your root `LinearLayout` in *my_item.xml*:

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `onTouch` listener  , add the following classed on you project

**ClickListener.java**

```
  public interface ClickListener {
        void onClick(View view, int position);

        void onLongClick(View view, int position);
    }
```

**RecyclerTouchListener .java**

```
public class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

        private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
        private ClickListener clickListener;

        public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final ClickListener clickListener) {
            this.clickListener = clickListener;
            gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                    View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                    if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                        clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

            View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
            if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
                clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept)    {

        }
    }
```

Now where you set the adapter use this class like this

```
  myList .addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(this, myList , new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
              //do your stuff on click
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
                //do your stuff on ling click
            }
        }));

    }
```

Comment: This is one way of doing things, but the code snippet in the original question is just a snippet of a big project and it currently adds onClickListener inside the `onBind` method. The method you've suggested, while might be more optimal can't be integrated right now. Thanks anyway :)